# How to set vm computer's name from host machine using powershell?

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I found an article about [Rename the guest OS to match the virtual machine name on Hyper-V](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2013/05/13/rename-the-guest-os-to-match-the-virtual-machine-name-on-hyper-v.aspx) to rename computer name to match the vm's name. The problem is this script has to attached on the virtual machine and it's going to be hard if I want to change it.

Is it possible to rename vm computer's name from the host machine?

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try, you can run it on the host. Currently it just prints a message of the old and new vm name. I left two options (commented out) in the code to rename the machine. Keep in mind that the machines should be resolvable and preferably part of your domain (you might need to remove the domain extensions from the vm name).

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\virtualization\v2 -Class Msvm_ComputerSystem | Where-Object {$_.ElementName -ne $env:COMPUTERNAME} | ForEach-Object { 

    $newName = $_.ElementName

    $_.GetRelated('Msvm_KvpExchangeComponent').GuestIntrinsicExchangeItems | ForEach-Object {  

        if($_ -as [xml])
        {    
            $GuestExchangeItemXml = ([XML]$_).SelectSingleNode("/INSTANCE/PROPERTY[@NAME='Name']/VALUE[child::text()='FullyQualifiedDomainName']") 

            if ($GuestExchangeItemXml -ne $null) 
            {
                $vmName = $GuestExchangeItemXml.SelectSingleNode("/INSTANCE/PROPERTY[@NAME='Data']/VALUE/child::text()").Value -replace '\W','_'
                $vmName = $vmName.Substring(0,[System.Math]::Min(15,$vmName.Length))

                #(Get-WmiObject Win32_Computersystem -ComputerName $vmName).Rename($newName); shutdown -r -t 0 
                #Rename-Computer -ComputerName $vmName -NewName $newName -Restart -Force -WhatIf 

                Write-Host "Renaming $vmName to $newName"           
            }  
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Rename-Computer` cmdlet:

```
Rename-Computer -ComputerName OldServerName -NewName NewServerName -Restart -Force
```

`Rename-Computer` does not use Powershell remoting so it is possible to run even without remote commands being enabled. See the [docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849792.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the hostname in the guest if you're able to connect to the remote host over the network.

```
$oldname = 'foo'
$newname = 'bar'

(Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem -Computer $oldname).Rename($newname)

Restart-Computer $oldname
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple command execute it through power shell

(gwmi win32_computersystem).Rename("NewName"); shutdown -r -t 0

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short one

> Invoke-Command -VMName "vm name here" -ScriptBlock { 
>   Rename-Computer -NewName "new name here" 
>   }

Answer (score 0):

For VM-s running Windows, this is very easy to achieve using the  [PowerShell Direct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/powershell-direct) feature which allows to:

> run arbitrary PowerShell in a Windows (...) virtual machine from your Hyper-V host regardless of network configuration or remote management settings.

such as:

> PowerShell Direct with Invoke-Command is perfect for situations where you need to run one command or one script on a virtual machine but do not need to continue interacting with the virtual machine beyond that point.

First, on host machine, create credential object with credentials of your administrator user on the target VM, either being prompt for details

```
$credential = Get-Credential
```

or filling the object manually:

```
$username = "Administrator"   # administrator user on target VM
$password = "Secr3tPa$$w0rd"  # of administrator user on target VM
$passwordSecureString = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
$password.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object { $passwordSecureString.AppendChar($_) }
$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $passwordSecureString
```

Finally, on host machine, run the command to rename the VM:

```
$vmName = 'vm-mywin'
$vmNewComputerName = 'worker1'
Invoke-Command -VMName $vmName -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock { `
  Rename-Computer -NewName $vmNewComputerName; `
  Restart-Computer  -Force;
}
```